# Google geolocalization

Tags: google-maps

Got one question about geolocalization from google maps.

Assume we have small city, which doesn't have any street marked on google maps.
Geolocalization works fine when I don't provide street in query, but with street provided, the result is totally messed up.

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I was confronted with the same problem some time ago.

I contacted google and told them that they should retry the geolocalization without the street name if no result has been found. They told me that they are working on a solution for this and that they are constantly building up their database of street names.

I ended up with doing one API call with the street name if result is not appropriate i retry without the street name.

Comment: But, how to find out that result isn't appropriate?

Comment: Do you get a full result if you do a request with the street name? in which way is it different from the result without the street name?

Comment: It points me to totally different city. Take a look: [without a street](http://maps.google.com/maps?q=nowy+zmigrod+&hl=pl&ie=UTF8&sll=49.978015,19.476903&sspn=1.282335,2.469177&hnear=Nowy+%C5%BBmigr%C3%B3d,+jasielski,+Podkarpackie,+Polska&t=m&z=15) vs [with a street](http://maps.google.com/maps?q=nowy+zmigrod+rynek+32&hl=pl&ie=UTF8&sll=49.603563,21.523813&sspn=0.020192,0.038581&hq=nowy+zmigrod&hnear=Rynek+G%C5%82%C3%B3wny,+27,+31-000+Krak%C3%B3w,+ma%C5%82opolskie,+Polska&t=m&z=9)

Comment: are the city names included in the geocoding result?

Comment: Yes, address output is different for request with or without city.

Comment: for me i didn't get a result when street name was included. but you can compare if the city in the result matches the city in the request? not a perfect solution but a workaround